# Django-Python3-LDAP Direct Bind

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, active-directory

Is it possible to direct bind to AD with django-python3-ldap? I know search and bind is possible, but this requires someone's AD password to be accessible to other members of the team (i.e. in an environment variable on the server where the Django app is hosted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish this if you set these settings to `None`:

```
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME = None
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD = None
```

From the README:

> The LDAP username and password of a user for querying the LDAP
>   database for user details. If None, then the authenticated user will
>   be used for querying, and the `ldap_sync_users` command will perform
>   an anonymous query.

I haven't tested it with AD but it works with OpenLDAP. Good luck!